# Story ID from an in-text poem about dragons

Tags: story-identification, novel, dragons, quotes

I read this book, maybe 8 years ago or a bit more.  It is fantasy, and humor, and I think part of it was set here and part in a low-tech magical world.  I believe one of the characters was a math teacher, maybe his (?) chapter titles were math equations?  It was quite important that he knew math, it might've been significant in the other world as well.  and I think another was studying magic and maybe was commuting back and forth between the worlds for her study and her day job.  What I recall most right now was this little poem, in the text of the book.

> There's a dragon on the cover of the book/
>   a dragon on the cover of the book/
>   It is green and it has scales/
>   and it is no-where in this tale/
>   but there's a dragon on the cover of the book!

I genuinely do not recall if there was a dragon on the cover.  I don't think there was a dragon in the story, although they were perhaps discussing the possibility when the one character starts singing the poem as a joke (and it was not given any other author but the character).

I have not had much luck searching for it, with keywords, quotes, or snippets.  Putting the whole thing in quotes is also not working.  I am hoping someone else might remember better.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever get a copy of the "Hounding the moon" book? To know if this question can be marked as answered? :)

Answer (score 7):

This poem appears in ***Hounding the Moon*, by P.R.Frost**. Some of the text is on Google Books (which is how I found it - I'm surprised it didn't come up for you!).

Google offers the following extract:

> After several long moments of grieving silence, someone in the back of
> the room, maybe Gollum, maybe someone who'd known Bob longer, struck
> up a rousing chorus of a folk song on a guitar. A flute and drum
> joined him. Then we all burst into the best folk song ever written.
>
> *There's a bimbo on the cover of my book./
> There's a bimbo on the cover of my book./ She is blonde and she is sexy;/ She is nowhere in the text.
> She/ Is a bimbo on the cover of the book.*

The verse you quoted is the fourth verse, as follows:

> *There's a dragon on the cover of the book./ There's a dragon on the
> cover of the book. He is long and green and scaly,/ But he's nowhere in
> the tale. He/ Is a dragon on the cover of the book.*

You can find the whole ditty [here on Tumblr](http://pitviperofdoom.tumblr.com/post/98827153973/theres-a-bimbo-on-the-cover-of-my-book-theres-a), attributed to "P.R. Frost and others" (it specifies it should be sung to the tune of "She'll be Coming Round the Mountain").

The book is the first in the Tess Noincare series, apparently. A summary of the book is offered [on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0756404258):

> Readers who crave the fantasy equivalent of a summer movie will
> welcome Frost's debut, which introduces Tess Noncoiré, a widowed
> writer who has joined the Goddess-worshiping Sisterhood of the
> Celestial Blade Warriors, sworn to protect the dimensional portal
> between humanity and demonkind. Thanks to her magical bond with the
> wisecracking, cigar-smoking imp Scrap, who changes form to become her
> Celestial Blade, Tess fights evil—even in the middle of a busy
> schedule of appearances at science fiction conventions and bookstores
> to flog her bestselling fantasy novels based on the Sisterhood. When
> Tess saves a Native American girl from an apparent hellhound attack,
> she's drawn into a complex plot to open the portal between Earth and
> the demon realms.

I can't verify the specifics of what you said, but it does offer the idea of a double life - someone commuting between a day job selling books, and a world fighting demons. It also sounds like it mixes fantasy and humour. I'm not sure about the math teacher.

It was first published in 2006, so "eight years ago or more" would fit.

This is the cover - no dragon, but a small imp-like creature:

[image]

Comment: Also, I totally have this song in my head now.

Comment: I expect it didn't come up in my search because the one I was searching for has a somewhat different third line - so didn't match in quotes.  The lyrics match really well otherwise.  However, it doesn't seem to match my memories - neither the extended song nor the book or plot is resonating with me.  (Which is not your fault, this is a brilliant answer - there's a lot of useful context).  I'm planning to get a hold of the book, to see if reading it will help before accepting the answer.  Thank you, though!